# Create dictionary using cell values from two columns of excel

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have an excel sheet with columns ISIN and URL as header as shown below:

```
*ISIN   URL*

ISIN1   https://mylink3.pdf
ISIN2   https://mylink2.pdf
```

I need to create a dictionary of the values of this sheet and have used the below code:

```
import pandas as pd

my_dic = pd.read_excel('PDFDwn.xlsx', index_col=0).to_dict()
print(my_dic)
```

The output that I receive is as below.

```
{'URL': {'ISIN1': 'https://mylink3.pdf', 'ISIN2': 'https://mylink2.pdf'}}
```

whereas expected output should be as below without URL piece.

```
{'ISIN1': 'https://mylink3.pdf', 'ISIN2': 'https://mylink2.pdf'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
print df.set_index('ISIN')['URL'].to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'ISIN2': 'https://mylink2.pdf', 'ISIN1': 'https://mylink3.pdf'}
```

As Per User sample:

```
my_dic = pd.read_excel('PDFDwn.xlsx', index_col=0).set_index('ISIN')['URL'].to_dict()
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammad.. Can you please specify what df stands for or may be share the complete code?

Comment: @ShashiShankarSingh - added to the solution

Comment: return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: '*ISIN'

Comment: @ShashiShankarSingh - `*ISIN` is this column available in your file or not. please edit column names as per your requirement

Comment: please check all any spaces over there or not.

Comment: you can try this, df=pd.read_excel('PDFDwn.xlsx', index_col=0)
print df.columns, you can sent this result here then i could try to help

Comment: Index(['URL'], dtype='object')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172232/discussion-between-mohamed-thasin-ah-and-shashi-shankar-singh).

Comment: As suggested Thasin....                                                                   
my_dic = pd.read_excel('PDFDwn.xlsx').set_index('ISIN')['URL'].to_dict()

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
my_dic['URL']
```

Output:

```
{'ISIN1': 'https://mylink3.pdf', 'ISIN2': 'https://mylink2.pdf'}
```